# Mybatis association in one-one in model but one-many in database : No crash?

Tags: java, mybatis

We noticed something a bit wrong with MyBatis.

Let's say I have this :

```
class Player {
    String id;
    Account account;
}

class Account {
    String id;
    Integer money;
}
```

And resulting MyBatis mapper :

```
  <resultMap id="playerMap" type="fr.my.project.PlayerBean">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <association property="account" javaType="fr.my.project.AccountBean">
      <id column="idAccount" property="id" />
      <result column="money" property="money" />
    </association>
  </resultMap>
```

Until this point, no problem.

Now, for some reason, we had the problem that several Player managed to link more Account that the only one in the database, because our database model allowed that, helped by bug in our app...

So the one-to-one relationship between Player and Account become a one-to-many in database, but still a one-to-one in Java model.

Problem is that when I looked for Player by id, I retrieved a random Account on Java, without any complain from MyBatis. So very hard to notice that problem !

Is there a way to say to MyBatis to not reducing a collection to an association, throwing a TooManyResultException or and exception like this ? MyBatis shouldn't act like that when he has a list instead of a unique potential object...

*We corrected the problem using collection instead of association in the MyBatis mapper, and adding a list of Account in the Player class at the end...*

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship changed from "one-to-one" to "one-to-many" you should:

- Use the `<collection>` tag instead of the `<association>` tag. **Associations** will only keep one *random* related row (discarding all the other ones), while **Collections** will retrieve them all.
- Your bean should have a `List<Account> account` property now instead of a simple `Account account`, in order to accommodate multiple accounts per player.

See [Advanced Result Maps](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Advanced_Result_Maps) for an example on how to use a collection.

Comment: I know how to use collection / association, but when the relationship is not the same in the database than in the model, it's strange... Is "keep one random related row" the default behavior ? I would like to avoid this behavior and make MyBatis crash on that.

Comment: @Guillaume The `<collection>` and `<association>` tags have nothing to do with the relationship in the database. They just represent the cardinality the query will produce.

Comment: But when you ask for an object in a query and you get a list, I got an exception TooManyResultException. Not in the case of a relationship.